# I cannot make a column's details visible in an SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010

I am somewhat new to SSRS so there is a reasonable chance I have overlooked something, but I have tried experimenting with this financial report for days as I try to get one particular column to be visible without success.

This report came from our portfolio accounting system vendor, but can be customized by clients. I realize no one can actually run the report without having access to the database the dataset points to but I included the rdl files in case it's helpful to see why the **Security Symbol column** will not show the details in that particular column, it will only show the column header.

I've attached the rdl file too. One thing I noticed is that whomever designed the report somehow was able to make some columns extend horizontally to also include row detail? They are not strictly vertical. They also were able to selectively include information within column groups. I have only made columns that are strictly vertical and grows that don't somehow snake around text boxes like this report does? I'd like to learn more how they were able to customize columns and column groups to do this.

My end goal is to simply make the security symbol column details visible. There should be information in that column with tickers like aapl, msft, goog etc but it is empty, showing only the column header.

Regular Column vertical only
[image: Regular Column vertical only]

When you select this column it also contains rows?
[image: Irregular Column also contains rows?]

Row Groupings omit certain text boxes. The designer was able to snake around information?
[image: Row Groupings omit certain text boxes]

Symbol column with variable for visibility
[image: Symbol column with variable for visibility]

I removed the variable for testing
[image: Variable removed]

However the Symbol column details are still missing
[image: Symbol column details are still missing]

Link to rdl file
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/Copy%20of%20PortfolioAppraisal.rdl

Thank you

**Answered by Ann L**

Show Security Symbol Parameter current setting.

[image: Current]

Set to true

[image: True]

New Parameter selector is unlocked

[image: True]

Report shows correct result set

[image: True]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one complex report, possibly one of the more complex that I've seen.

According to the .rdl file, one of the parameters to the report is `@ShowSecuritySymbol`.  Although I can't tell without seeing the source to the stored procedure `APXSSRS.pReportAppraisal`, which seems to be what returns all this data we're seeing, it's possible the procedure was coded in such a way that the value just isn't returned unless `@ShowSecuritySymbol` is true.  That would account for what you're seeing.

When you run the report, are you providing a value for `@ShowSecuritySymbol`?  And is it `True`?

Incidentally, I think the reason you can select a column and it appears to also select rows, is that the cells in that row were merged so that the selected column, in that row, goes all the way across that row.

Comment: Ann that is the answer. I've updated my question to show the result. Thank you.

Comment: If anyone is still reading this. What does the =NOT in the variable expression field accomplish?

Comment: The `=` is used in the expression field as an assignment statement, and the `NOT` is from Visual Basic syntax.  It negates whatever follows.  Essentially it's the `!` from C#.  So, in English, it's saying, "Assign to the property 'hidden' the negative of the (Boolean) field `SecuritySymbolIsVisible`'s value for this record".

Comment: So it's saying the default value is NOT visible? Also I found out that security symbol selector had always been available. I just didn't see it. However the default was set to hidden. After setting the default value as True it then defaulted to visible. I could then toggle it to hidden if I wanted.

Comment: It's a little complicated:  the property that controls visibility is called `Hidden`, so a value of True means the field isn't rendered.  However, it defaults to False.  The UI for the Hidden property obscures this, because it calls itself "Visibility" (not "hiddenness") and because the options are Show, Hide, and Expression.  But if you set it to an expression you have to remember that it's the opposite of what you'd intuitively expect:  True means "hide" and False means "show".